# Poetry: Poetry install -- with ui (ERROR: Group(s) not found: ui (via --with)

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-poetry, privategpt

I am following this guide from https://dev.to/docteurrs/installing-privategpt-on-wsl-with-gpu-support-1m2a  that Network Chuck said was excellent in his most recent YT-video.

Anyway, I follow the steps and all is fine, until I get to

```
cd privateGPT
poetry install --with ui
poetry install --with local
```

In the PrivateGPT folder it returns:

Group(s) not found: ui (via --with)

Group(s) not found: local (via --with)

Does anyone have any idea why this is? I've tried twice now, I reinstallted the WSL and Ubuntu fresh to retrace my steps, but I encounter the same issue once again. And help is appreciated :)

I've tried twice now, I reinstallted the WSL and Ubuntu fresh to retrace my steps, but I encounter the same issue once again. The Path seems to be correct as told in the guide, and the bashrc seems to run correctly upon startup so no errors there.

However it could be possible that poetry should be in the home/user/privateGPT  folder instead of home/user/.local/bin that it autoinstalls into?

Answer (score 2):

The guide that you're following is outdated as of last week. Installation changed with [commit 45f0571](https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT/commit/45f05711eb71ffccdedb26f37e680ced55795d44)

I can't pretend to understand the full scope of the change or the intent of the guide that you linked (because I only skimmed the relevant commands), but I looked into `pyproject.toml` and it's clear that `ui` has moved from its own group to the `extras`. So now the command to install it is:

`poetry install --extras "ui"`

I don't know where `local` went or what it is supposed to to, so maybe the official docs will help. Perhaps the section titled *Local, Ollama-powered setup - RECOMMENDED* is what you need?

https://docs.privategpt.dev/installation/getting-started/main-concepts
https://docs.privategpt.dev/installation/getting-started/installation

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and answer, now it seems like it will work! Appreciate it very much sir :)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. With the answer given by picobit I was able to look through the commit changes and saw the changes mentioned.

Running the command:

```
poetry install --extras "ui embeddings-huggingface llms-llama-cpp vector-stores-qdrant"
```

then following the guide I was able to finish the walkthrough with no issue after that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just got mine up and running wih the same, all need to be in there at one time for sucessful install

poetry install --extras "ui embeddings-huggingface llms-llama-cpp vector-stores-qdrant"

Answer (score 0):

I tried
poetry install -extras ui
It installed all dependencies in the current project

Thank you for all the leads here. It helped